# how to get each value from after loop

Tags: java, hibernate

i have got list using this , now how can i get each element in for each loop?

```
public String execute(){
    Query query=HibernateUtil.currentSession().createSQL("SELECT u.id,u.orderId,p.productName,u.key2,i.for_sponsor_id FROM useller_orders u join prod on p.productId=u.productId "
            + "join ir i on u.key2=i.id where p.productName like '%FEE%'"
            + " and u.createdDate > '" + createdDate + "' "
            + "and forced_matrix_sponsor_id is null "
            + "order by u.key2");
    List<Object> list = query.list();
```

I want to get that U.ID to print in loop

Comment: Did you want to use [HQL](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/), or did you want to use SQL? Because your query looks like SQL.

Comment: Are you in search of `for (Object record : list) { /* do something with record */ }` ?

Comment: @Sundara I would assume because (a) it's not clear what you want, and (b) understanding how to iterate in both Java and JSP is well-documented, and fairly easy to search for.

Comment: @DaveNewton so you did -ve vote

Comment: I didn't, but what if I did? It's a poor question for which much documentation exists.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay thank you for suggestion. Next time i will not ask this type of question. I will try to solve it by myself. I will only ask Very hard doubts!   I don know you remember or not many time you have suggested me to read from basic.. I think past 1yr you have suggested me on few of my question posts. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html), the list that's returned is a list of object arrays.  So you'll need to change your last line to

```
List<Object[]> list = query.list();
```

Then write

```
for (Object[] arr : list) {
    System.out.println(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should be discouraged by the downvote.  There are so many people using Stack Overflow, it's hard to please all of them.  It's not really worth being upset about.  Maybe your next question or answer will get lots of upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the 'foreach' loop:

```
for (Object o : list) {

}
```

If you know in some way the specific type of the elements contained in the list you can also cast:

```
for (Object o : list) {
   TheClass item = (TheClass)o;
   // use the item    
}
```

Comment: i want u.id to be printed on that loop

Comment: @Sundara, are you expecting people to just give you the code? Come on, try SOMETHING yourself!

Comment: I can help you if you say me exactly what is the class of the objects contained in the list, and maybe also the API of this class.